# UIView Composite mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

Is there any way to change the composite mode of a UIView background say to screen, overlay, or multiply?

The effect I am trying to go for is similar to what appears in the iOS notification centre where the cell background is much darker, however still translucent to the background. This looks to me like a multiply effect in photoshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what your referring to but play around with the background colour and alpha

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
view.alpha           = 0.4f; // Try changing this to suit
```

They may be using subtle gradients and other additional embellishments to really fine tune the look.

---

## Update

I can get a fairly convincing reproduction using

```
backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.37f];
whitePixelLine  = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.8f alpha:0.4f];
darkPixelLine   = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.6f];
```

My graphic skills are terrible so this could be way off the mark

Comment: I tried this a few ways, however adjusting the alpha just fades the background where if you look at the notification centre the contrast is much higher.

Comment: Can you add an example I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe compare it to your experiments to show the difference

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, I could probably make that work. Also, I did find what I was looking for in terms of compositing modes (blending modes).

self.view.layer.compositingFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIMultiplyCompositing"];

However, I may not end up needing it. Thanks